# An error when creating new project in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

**Every time I create new project i get this error:**

```
Failed to import new Gradle project: Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read below process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.


Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

**Any Idea?**

Comment: Did you go into the "Help | Show Log" section there? Also, it's a very early build, not meant for production work, so I don't recommend wasting much time with it if it's giving errors so often.

Comment: I had this problem yesterday, but today I open the studio and it works. It may be a problem with Internet connection. Try reopen it.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Start Android Studio, close any open project.

On the right side, click on Configure -> Settings.

On the left side, in Compiler->Gradle set VM Options to "-Xmx512m" (without quotes)

Press OK, then create a project. Worked for me.

Comment: Works for me. Looks like gradle wrapper default is too low.

Comment: This worked for me when I switched from 64-bit JDK to 32-bit JDK and started getting this error.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)  Why Android Studio is not adding default config?

Comment: In Android Studio version 1.2.2, this setting has been moved to **Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle**

Answer (score 29):

64 bit users!

There is a chance Gradel is looking at a 32 bit JDK install. So we need to change that (worked for me).

Start -> type "Environment" -> click "Edit System Environment Variables" -> a dialog will pop up, click the button labeled "Environment Variables" -> locate JAVA_HOME set it to "C:\Program Files\Java\$YOUR_JAVA_VER" where $YOUR_JAVA_VER = jdk1.7.0_21.

If there is no JAVA_HOME you may need to create it, when I read the install Wiki I was told I needed to install it.

Comment: Thanks Tunix, I was missing the JAVA_HOME EV, and this did the trick

Comment: This works for me. My JAVA_HOME EV was the 32 bits version. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Antivirus block Java and Android studio.
Try to close antivirus and check again...

Comment: Amazing!!! After trying everything here said by many and still no success. I tried to test this and it worked .... god!!! ... weeks lost in the antivirus. For the record I'm using Kaspersky Internet Security 2013

Comment: If anyone encounters this now - change Antivirus software, a false positive on Java/Android Studio is awful

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried everything as well, and it's finally fixed! I already disabled McAfee but forgot to also disable Malwarebytes anti-exploit. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

for me it works by setting up environment variable

```
GRADLE_OPTS=-Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project and find gradle.propeties and then find:- "org.gradle.jnmargs"  replace this line with followings 
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxHeapSize\=256m -Xmx256m

Error in stable version of android-studio 2.2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) can help you write answers that will be accepted and upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

My answer was found with Android Studio 2.2, which released in September of 2016, so the previous answers that are on this post did not work for me. What did work for me, however, is setting Android Studio to use the integrated JDK instead of the JDK 1.8 that I downloaded. Before setting my JDK to the integrated JDK and not the one I downloaded, I got the same errors as detailed in this post.

This can be found in your Default Project Structure settings. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to decrease setting for max heap space setting in the file

```
android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\dx.bat
```

to smaller value. change it to 512M instead of 1024M.

```
set defaultMx=-Xmx512M
```

Comment: Android studio is Bundle with sdk.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of Android Studio (0.2.1 as of this answer), you can go to Android Studio Preferences, expand the Compiler options, and attempt to reduce the maximum allowed memory for the Java Compiler, Groovy Compiler, and Android DX Compiler. Keep reducing until you see a change in outcome. Honestly, it sounds like your computer may just be short on available RAM, and Android Studio may be configured by default to take up a relatively large chunk of memory.

Answer (score 0):

put the option: -Xmx512m in the compiler >> grandle VM options, not in the general compiler VM options, Don't Replace -ea

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by go to ANDROID_SDKPATH/sdk/build-tools/VERSION/dx.bat edit with some text editor
change `set java_exe=`

to

```
set java_exe=%java_home%\bin\java.exe
```

or use your java.exe path

and comment

```
if exist    "%~dp0..\tools\lib\find_java.bat" call    "%~dp0..\tools\lib\find_java.bat"
if exist "%~dp0..\..\tools\lib\find_java.bat" call "%~dp0..\..\tools\lib\find_java.bat"
```

result like this

```
set java_exe=%java_home%\bin\java.exe
rem if exist    "%~dp0..\tools\lib\find_java.bat" call    "%~dp0..\tools\lib\find_java.bat"
rem if exist "%~dp0..\..\tools\lib\find_java.bat" call "%~dp0..\..\tools\lib\find_java.bat"
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
```

and now it can BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Answer (score 0):

Open Gradle Properties and change the org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m.

and then click try again to synchronize Gradle again.

[See The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix2t6.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

- Open your Android **Studio >> File >> Settings >> Compiler >> Gradle**
- Set *VM Options* to `-Xmx512m` and OK.